# List Filter. Condition for No Matches Found. How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, html-lists

I have found a pretty cool example from [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_filters.asp) that helped me learn how to create a search filter.

I have customized it bellow for everyone to see.

I would like to know how I can modify it to display just a list item with a message that reads: **No matches found.** I have a bit of a **challenge understanding** the **logic behind toggle** in this example *as it hides items that do not match* **instead of** *showing items that do match*.

I believe this is the part where the logic for No Matches Found is to be placed?

Perhaps someone could post an approach to it.

Thank you

```js
// CUSTOM SCRIPT

// List Filter
$(document).ready(function(){
  // On KeyUp...
  $("#input_search_client").on("keyup", function() {
    // All values typed in to lower case...
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $("#list_search_client a").filter(function() {

      // Hide if it does not match
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);

    });
  });
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Google Material Design Icons -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

<form>
  <!-- CARD INTRO -->
  <section class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-3">
    <!-- CARD INTRO LEFT -->
    <div class="text-center">
      <h1 class="mb-0 display-4">Search</h1>
      <h4 class="mb-0">Active Clients</h4>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- CARD INTRO END -->


  <!-- SECTION - FEX.GRID - JUSTIFY CENTER -->
  <section class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center mb-2">
    <!-- COL-6 - FEX.COLUMN - ELEMENT -->
    <div class="col-6 px-0">
        <input class="form-control form-control-lg px-2" value="" id="input_search_client" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- SECTION - FEX.GRID - JUSTIFY START -->
  <section class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center mb-2">
    <!-- COL-6 - FEX.COLUMN - ELEMENT -->
    <div class="col-6 px-0">
      <div class="list-group" id="list_search_client">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Elliot Alderson</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Darlene Alderson</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Angela Moss</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Sarah Connor</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <hr>

</form>
```

Comment: That is a really poor example they have for using filter(). They are using it incorrectly. A filter should return a boolean. For their use it should be just an `each`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to hiding non-matches with `.toggle()`, you'll want to build an `if` conditional that checks for the presence of the searched text. This will be triggered when **each** result is found. Inside this conditional, you'll want to set a **flag** (in this example, `found`) that denotes that a result has been found.

This flag must initially be set to `false`, and must be set inside of the `keyup` function, but **outside** of the `indexOf(value)` conditional (as you want to loop over **all** of the searchable results before realising that no match has been made).

From here it's just a matter of using `.hide()` and `.show()` to show the element that you wish to display when no result is found. Note that this element should be hidden by default.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
// CUSTOM SCRIPT

// List Filter
$(document).ready(function() {
  // On KeyUp...
  $("#input_search_client").on("keyup", function() {
    // No results have been found yet
    let found = false;
    
    // All values typed in to lower case...
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $("#list_search_client a").filter(function() {
      // Hide if it does not match
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);

      if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1) {
        // Results found
        $('.none-found').hide();
        found = true;
      }

      // No results found
      if (!found) {
        $('.none-found').show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.list-group.none-found {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Google Material Design Icons -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

<form>
  <!-- CARD INTRO -->
  <section class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-3">
    <!-- CARD INTRO LEFT -->
    <div class="text-center">
      <h1 class="mb-0 display-4">Search</h1>
      <h4 class="mb-0">Active Clients</h4>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- CARD INTRO END -->


  <!-- SECTION - FEX.GRID - JUSTIFY CENTER -->
  <section class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center mb-2">
    <!-- COL-6 - FEX.COLUMN - ELEMENT -->
    <div class="col-6 px-0">
      <input class="form-control form-control-lg px-2" value="" id="input_search_client" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- SECTION - FEX.GRID - JUSTIFY START -->
  <section class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center mb-2">
    <!-- COL-6 - FEX.COLUMN - ELEMENT -->
    <div class="col-6 px-0">
      <div class="list-group" id="list_search_client">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Elliot Alderson</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Darlene Alderson</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Angela Moss</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Sarah Connor</a>
      </div>
      <div class="list-group none-found">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">No results found.</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <hr>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add an element to the results which is hidden by default- have it set to "No Results Found", or whatever you want. Then check the size of visible elements. Based on the size- toggle showing or hiding your "No Results Found" dialog.

There's definitely more elegant solutions but this is short and simple! Just a few extra lines. Here is my snippet

```js
// CUSTOM SCRIPT

// List Filter
$(document).ready(function(){
  // On KeyUp...
  $("#input_search_client").on("keyup", function() {
    // All values typed in to lower case...
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $("#list_search_client a").filter(function() {

      // Hide if it does not match
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
      if ($("#list_search_client a").filter(":visible").length < 1){
        $("#list_search_client :last-child").show();
      }
      else{
        $("#list_search_client :last-child").hide();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Google Material Design Icons -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

<form>
  <!-- CARD INTRO -->
  <section class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-3">
    <!-- CARD INTRO LEFT -->
    <div class="text-center">
      <h1 class="mb-0 display-4">Search</h1>
      <h4 class="mb-0">Active Clients</h4>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- CARD INTRO END -->


  <!-- SECTION - FEX.GRID - JUSTIFY CENTER -->
  <section class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center mb-2">
    <!-- COL-6 - FEX.COLUMN - ELEMENT -->
    <div class="col-6 px-0">
        <input class="form-control form-control-lg px-2" value="" id="input_search_client" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- SECTION - FEX.GRID - JUSTIFY START -->
  <section class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center mb-2">
    <!-- COL-6 - FEX.COLUMN - ELEMENT -->
    <div class="col-6 px-0">
      <div class="list-group" id="list_search_client">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Elliot Alderson</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Darlene Alderson</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Angela Moss</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Sarah Connor</a>
        <a style="display:none" href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">No Results Found</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <hr>

</form>
```

Comment: I find this approach interesting although it seems to use 2 filters.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your code in a similar way Obsidian Age did.

But I based the condition to show a "no result" `div` on the amount of **visible** (unfiltered) element. If there is none... There is clearly no results.

```js
// CUSTOM SCRIPT

// List Filter
$(document).ready(function(){
  // On KeyUp...
  $("#input_search_client").on("keyup", function() {
    // All values typed in to lower case...
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#list_search_client a").filter(function() {

      // Hide if it does not match
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
    });
    
    // If there is no achor visible, show the "no result" div
    if($("#list_search_client a:visible").length==0){
      $(".noresult").show();
    }else{
      $(".noresult").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.noresult{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Google Material Design Icons -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

<form>
  <!-- CARD INTRO -->
  <section class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-3">
    <!-- CARD INTRO LEFT -->
    <div class="text-center">
      <h1 class="mb-0 display-4">Search</h1>
      <h4 class="mb-0">Active Clients</h4>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- CARD INTRO END -->


  <!-- SECTION - FEX.GRID - JUSTIFY CENTER -->
  <section class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center mb-2">
    <!-- COL-6 - FEX.COLUMN - ELEMENT -->
    <div class="col-6 px-0">
        <input class="form-control form-control-lg px-2" value="" id="input_search_client" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- SECTION - FEX.GRID - JUSTIFY START -->
  <section class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center mb-2">
    <!-- COL-6 - FEX.COLUMN - ELEMENT -->
    <div class="col-6 px-0">
      <div class="list-group" id="list_search_client">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Elliot Alderson</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Darlene Alderson</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Angela Moss</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Sarah Connor</a>
      </div>
      <div class="noresult">
      No result
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <hr>

</form>
```